# How to fetch data from search list via API

Tags: ruby, data.com

We created a simple search list and saved it under "Saved Searches" which contains lots of user information. (` 5K users)

I would like to retrieve user information (Name, Title ..) using an API call. What call should I use to fetch this information in a paginated fashion.

Comment: How have you created your 'Saved Search'?

Comment: Yes, "the saved search has been created manually"

Comment: How did you do this? What options did you use in the UI/menus?

Comment: Are these [Data.com saved searches](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=jigsaw_int_saving_searches.htm&language=en_US)?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yes they are data.com saved searches...

Comment: @AlexTennant search for contacts or companies, sort them using left pane and save the search, everything happens in the UI

Comment: It would also be a great help to know the procedure to fetch data from data.com

Comment: I see you've used the Ruby tag. Are you wanting to use a Ruby on Rails App to query this data?

Comment: Yes, I would like to fetch this data using a ruby gem if available.

Comment: Appreciate if anyone could provide pointers on this discussion.

Comment: Isn't there a mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: Hasn't anyone tried this before? Appreciate any pointers.